# Django: provide choices list to a checkbox from a view function

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, choicefield

in my Django application I've got a form with a ChoiceField that normally allows to choice between a range of integer values.

```
class FormNumber(forms.Form):
list=[]
for i in range(1, 11):
    list.append((i,i))
number=forms.ChoiceField(choices=list, initial=1)
```

Now I need to override the default choices list from a view method in some cases, using a smaller range, but trying to do it in this way

```
n=10-len(request.session["items"])
    if n>0:
        list=[]
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            list.append((i,i))
        form=FormNumber(choices={'number':list}, initial={'number':1})
```

I get a TypeError - __ init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'. I tried also to remove the parameters from the form class, but I get the same result.

Is there a way to initialize the ChoiceField with a new choices list from the view in a way similar to the one above?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an `__init__(choices=None)` function to the form class `FormNumber` and initialize the ChoiceField `number` using that unless it's `None`.
If `choices` is not provided (defaults to `None`), initialization would do what it does by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to solve in this way, let's see what happens

Answer (score 2):

I post the code, maybe someone in future needs to solve a similar problem.

The form code now is this one:

```
class FormNumber(forms.Form): 
    def __init__(self, list=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormNumber, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["number"]=forms.ChoiceField(choices=list)
```

and I call it from the view simply with

```
form=FormNumber(list=number_list)
```